libbitsandbytes_cpu.dll failing on windows with error message 'can't find cget_managed_ptr'
I am trying to use bitsandbytes for finetuning on cpu by following instructions on huggingface. When I do trianer.train(), I get this error.
Here are the parameters to trainer.
`peft_config = LoraConfig(
        r=64,
        lora_alpha=16,
        target_modules="all-linear",
        bias="none",
        lora_dropout=0.1,
        #lora_dropout=0.1,
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM", #Siva: Should we use this?
        #task_type = "SEQ_CLS",
    )

    training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,  # directory to save and repository id
        num_train_epochs=3,  # number of training epochs
        per_device_train_batch_size=1,  # batch size per device during training
        gradient_accumulation_steps=8,  # number of steps before performing a backward/update pass
        gradient_checkpointing=True,  # use gradient checkpointing to save memory
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
        save_steps=0,
        logging_steps=25,  # log every 10 steps
        learning_rate=2e-4,  # learning rate, based on QLoRA paper
        weight_decay=0.001,
        fp16=False,
        bf16=True,
        max_grad_norm=0.3,  # max gradient norm based on QLoRA paper
        max_steps=-1,
        warmup_ratio=0.03,  # warmup ratio based on QLoRA paper
        group_by_length=True,
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",  # use cosine learning rate scheduler
        report_to="tensorboard",  # report metrics to tensorboard
        save_strategy = "epoch",
        load_best_model_at_end = True,
        evaluation_strategy="epoch"  # save checkpoint every epoch
    )
    #model = model.to(device)
    #peft_model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
    #peft_model = peft_model.to(device)
    #peft_model.to('cpu')
    trainer = SFTTrainer(
        model= model, #peft_model,
        args=training_arguments,
        train_dataset=train_data,
        eval_dataset=eval_data,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        dataset_text_field="text",
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        max_seq_length=1024,
        packing=False,
        dataset_kwargs={
            "add_special_tokens": False,
            "append_concat_token": False,
        }
    )`

Any pointers/help is greatly appreciated
I have tried degrade version from 0.4.2.2 to 0.4.2.1. The problem still persists. Tried to change the optimizer but without luck
